# Change datatype of one column from string to integer in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aws-lambda, lambda

I have data in Opensearch index like below :

Document 1:
units :"10"

Document 2:
units :" "

Document 3:
units :"20"

In lambda, I am using pandas for data transformation.
In final response I want output like below convert " " to null and string value to integer :
Document 1:
units :10

Document 2:
units :null

Document 3:
units :20

I tried with astype but it is giving me error like :
Cannot convert non finite values NA to integer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Document'] = [1, 2, 3]
df['units'] = ["10", " ", "20"]

df.loc[df["units"] == " ", "units"] = np.nan
df["units"] = df["units"].astype(float)
```

This would replace all `" "` with missing (`np.nan`) and convert the remaining string to floats (assuming they all contain only numeric characters).

You can't represent NaNs and integers in the same column in pandas directly, so floats would be the best alternative:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na

Output:

|  | Document | units |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 10.0 |
| 1 | 2 | NaN |
| 2 | 3 | 20.0 |

---

If you really wanted the column to be of integer type you could use one of the nullable-integer extension dtypes provided by pandas or pyarrow

```
df.loc[df["units"] == " ", "units"] = np.nan
df["units"] = df["units"].astype(float).astype(pd.Int64Dtype())
```

|  | Document | units |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 2 | NaN |
| 2 | 3 | 20 |